# PHP create hashtag links but NOT inside existent html code

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this regex to convert hash tags into clickable links:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/m', '<a href="/tag/$1">#$1</a>', $text, $maximum_tags);
```

The problem is that it also converts if my text contains html tags with styling:

```
<span style="color:#CCC;">FOO</span>
```

It would try to make a hashtag out of that #CCC , how should I modify the regex to only work outside of html tags ? E.g in plain text areas.

Answer (score 0):

The lexical effort to preg_replace conditionally towards existing markup is high, you should prefer to operate such contents as DOM (using `ext/dom` and its `DOMDocument` class architecture) and fetch and replace `DOMText` to bring hashtag-links into existing DOM.